# regex extract everything between the text and first > character

Tags: regex

I have the following string

```
CHG=U KEY=1234425850010A390K REVDATE=20200905><EFFECT EFFRG=343100></EFFECT><PNRMFR><PNR>344r0116-117</PNR>
<MFR>234322</MFR>
</PNRMFR>
<UPA>1</UPA>
<TQA>AR</TQA>
</ITEM>
<ITEM CHAPNBR=23 SECTNBR=45 UNITNBR=23 FIGNBR=123 ITEMNBR=123 ILLUSIND=1 INDENT=2 ATTACH=0 CHG=U KEY=R258500SWF395 REVDATE=20200905>
<ITEM CHAPNBR=34 SECTNBR=34 UNITNBR=12 FIGNBR=12 ITEMNBR=345k ILLUSIND=0 INDENT=1 ATTACH=0 CHG=D KEY=M11326334H567K REVDATE=20200905>
<DELETED>
</ITEM>
```

the regex expression i am using is the following :

```
((?<=REVDATE=).*(?=[^>]))
```

and the result i am getting is like this

```
["20200905><EFFECT EFFRG=003100></EFFECT><PNRMFR><PNR>415W0116-237</PNR>",'20200905>','20200905>']
```

How can i parse only the REVDATE from all the lines like

```
['20200905','20200905','20200905']
```

Comment: Maybe [`(?<=\bREVDATE=)\d+`](https://regex101.com/r/wdYcWo/1)

Comment: Thank you @JvdV, you can post it as an answer and i'll accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current pattern `((?<=REVDATE=).*(?=[^>]))` reads as follows:

- `(` - Open 1st capture group.

  - `(<=REVDATE=)` - Positive lookbehind for literally "REVDATE="
  - `.*` - Zero or more characters other than newline.
  - `(?=[^>])` - Positive lookahead for a character other than ">".
  - `)` - Close 1st capture group.

As you can [see](https://regex101.com/r/wdYcWo/2), that pattern is greedy. You told the engine to assert a position after "REVDATE=" and then ***greedily*** match any character other than newline right to the point where your positive lookahead finds anything other than ">" ***including*** a newline character! This is exactly the reason why it consumes the whole line up to the newline character (remember the `.*`).

---

You can correct this using a much simpler pattern:

```
(?<=\bREVDATE=)\d+
```

See the online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/wdYcWo/1)

- `(?<=\bREVDATE=)` - Positive lookbehind for a word-boundary followed by literally "REVDATE=".
- `\d+` - One ore more digits to capture your dates.

Comment: A pointer of what is wrong with the quality of the answer so I can improve it?

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, as a newbie i still struggle at regular expressions. this has helped me understand the error in my regex expression